# Knockout checkedValue keeps being set to "on"

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In the following code `pVM.People` and `pVM.PeopleSelected` are observable arrays.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: pVM.People">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: pVM.PeopleSelected" /></td>
    <td data-bind="text: $data.Name"></td>
  </tr>
<tbody>
```

When I check a box, all the boxes get selected, and if I look into the chrome javascript console, my array prints `["on"]` instead of having the objects in the list `pVM.People`.

I made a small thing in JSFiddle and the code works fine, so I know there is something more complex going on that is not being represented in the above code. However, the application is very large, and I am not even sure what to look for.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on why the objects are being converted to `"on"` when I check the boxes?

Comment: Somehow, the `checked` binding isn't seeing the `checkedValue` binding. Perhaps this is because of some preprocessing?

Comment: should checked be bound to `$root.pVM.PeopleSelected`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the wrong version of knockout. In knockout 2.3.0 apparently my solution above does not work.

Comment: Yes, `checkedValue` was added in version 3.0.0.